# Design Decision: OrderNumber property in Order class - Public or Private?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, modeling

I'm building an ordering system. And here I have an `Order` class, which has a property named `OrderNumber`. As you know, `OrderNumber` can only be assigned once, so I don't want to make it `public` (so I made it `private`).

However, **the order number is generated according to a sequencial value stored in database.**
For example, the value in database is 10, now I genearte an order number, the order number will be "`Year-Month-10`", and the value will increase to 11. The value will be reset every month.

You see, the order number generation **has a dependency to database**. If I make `OrderNumber` `private`, I can only call the generate order number method in the `Order` class (maybe in the constructor), that's not good and hard to do unit testing. And, I don't want to use any `ServiceLocator` in the `Order` class, I think it's **bad** too.

If I make the order number `public`, the problems above can be resolved. But the order number might be changed by some coders' mistake now, it's **not safe**.

So, can I make the `OrderNumber` property public? And your reasons?

**Updates:**

Thanks to Yahia for giving me a hint. 
Now I consider making OrderNumber property readonly, and pass the generator (e.g. IOrderNumberGenerator) to the constructor of the Order class.

**But there's another problem:** 
In my senario, the order number is **not** assigned when the Order object is created. The customer can create and save an order without passing the order to the order verifier. 
So before the order is passed to the order verifier, the order number is not assigned. OrderNumber is assigned only when the customer click the "**Request Order Verification**" button, and then the OrderNumber cannot be changed again. And the workflow moves to the next step (Order Verification).

I've created a new question, please look here: [Design Decision: Generate OrderNumber which depends on a database value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888352/design-decision-generate-ordernumber-which-depends-on-a-database-value)

**BTW**: I'm using C#

Thanks!

Comment: what about having a public readonly property `OrderNumber` based on a private field ?

Comment: Your update is a bit unclear... how do you find an order that has been saved without a unique order number ?

Comment: If you have an OrderNumberGenerator passed in the constructor but can't create the OrderNumber at that time keep a ref to the generator and call it when appropriate

Comment: No, the order can be saved without having the OrderNumber assigned. The order number is assigned only when the user click "Request Order Verification" button.

Comment: this is already the second update changing the question... please do NOT change your question in such way... if you have a second/third  question (like you do in this case) create a new question on SO... you can even put in a link to the "old question"...

Comment: Sorry, I've created a new question now, please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888352/design-decision-generate-ordernumber-which-depends-on-a-database-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend having a public readonly property `OrderNumber` (i.e. make `set` private) based on a private field... this gives you the benefits of both without any negative aspects.

Something you should consider:

Cases like the ones you describe are usually solved by implementing the Factory pattern...

**EDIT - regarding the update of the OP:**

Make a class `OrderNumber` and put it as a public property into your `Order` class.
The `OrderNumber class` has only private constructor and is only created via Factory pattern.

Thus your `Order` has initially `null` assigned to the `OrderNumber` property... this property has a `private set` method which only allows assignment when the internal field is `null`... to assign an `OrderNumber` you have for example a `Status` property which when changed to `Order Verification` calls the saved reference to `IOrderNumberGenerator` (from the constructor) and set the `OrderNumber` once...

Comment: Or `set` can be visible internal only, so the factory defined in the same assembly will be able to initialize it. Also the setter can contain a check that will throw an exception when you will try to modify an order number.

Comment: @DylanLin Your update is a bit unclear... how do you find an order that has been saved without a unique order number ?

Comment: The order also has an ID property (and it's the primary key in database).

Comment: Because the client don't want to waste OrderNumbers (the last part of the order number indicate the order index in that month). One can create an order and delete it before passed to verifer). The ordering steps are very complex, so we need to save the order in each step.

Comment: see my update above... please do NOT change your question in such way... if you have a second question (like you do in this case) create a new question on SO... you can even put a link to the "old question"...

Answer (score 1):

Remember, you can set the visibility of the get/set methods of a property:

```
public class Order
{
    private string orderNumber_;

    public string OrderNumber
    {
        get { return orderNumber_; }
        private set { orderNumber_ = value; }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Given your requirement, why not implement a second constructor, that takes an order number generator *and* an existing order?

```
public interface IOrderNumberGenerator
{
    string Generate();
}

public class Order
{
    private string orderNumber_;

    // default ctor
    public Order()
    {
    }   // eo ORder

    public Order(IOrderNumberGenerator generator, Order order)
    {
        orderNumber_ = generator.Generate();
        /* copy other fields from the existing Order*/
    }

    public string OrderNumber
    {
        get { return orderNumber_; }
    }
}   // eo class Order
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is not my question. Please see the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: @DylanLin, I've updated my answer with another possible solution.

Comment: Thanks, but there's another problem, please see my updates :)

Comment: @DylanLin, unless I am mistaken, I think this class handles it.  You can create an instance of `Order` without an order number and the user can work with it.  When you do the *Request Order Verification* step, you simply replace the order instance, e.g:  `Order verifiedOrder = new Order(OrderNumberGenerator(), existingOrder);`.  Or is there something else I am missing?

Comment: No, in the RequestOrderVerification step, the Order object is retrieved by calling repository.Get(orderId). I'm using an O/R Mapper. I've created a new question, look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888352/design-decision-generate-ordernumber-which-depends-on-a-database-value

Comment: Hi, I accepted Yahia's answer because he is the first one who pointed the Factory pattern. Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888352/design-decision-generate-ordernumber-which-depends-on-a-database-value